# "Glib.h: No such file or directory" error despite installing libglib2.0-dev

Tags: glib

I'm trying to make GROMACS the error I'm getting is :

`fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory`

I've seen that there are already  questions related to this, and I followed their advice and ran the following:

`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 270 not upgraded.
```

After this, when I re-run make,why do I it still get the same error?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem. You could try running `locate glib.h`. On my system the locate returns:

```
/home/jere/src/last.fm-1.4.2.58240/src/transcode/mpgli/mpglib/mpglib.h
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h
/usr/include/libdbusmenu-glib-0.4/libdbusmenu-glib/dbusmenu-glib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
```

and I ended up adding the `-I/usr/include/glib-2.0` to the include path of the compiler (in the Makefile).

I guess this is because not all linux distributions install the glib development files to the same folder.

Comment: How to add `/usr/include/glib-2.0` to the include path of MakeFile?

Comment: It depends on how the Makefile is written. Can you give me an example of your Makefile?

Comment: I was trying to set up [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy). Here is the [generated MakeFile](https://gist.github.com/revathskumar/8431625)

Comment: I have not tried this, but I can see there is a file https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/blob/master/src/Makefile.am You could try adding the `-I/usr/include/glib-2.0` to the `AM_CPPFLAGS` variable so that it looks like this: `AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0` and then reruning the `autogen.sh` script.